# how to use solr json.facet with aggregations in solrj

Tags: solr, solrj, facet

I am new to solr. I want to use json.facet with buckets and aggregation like sum or avg using solrj.
Is it already implemented in solrj?. I am not able to find any document or example of using json.facet in solrj.

It would be nice to have an example of solrj implementation of something like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/query -d 'q=*:*&rows=0&
json.facet={
     categories:{
        type : terms,
        field : cat,
        sort : { x : desc},
        facet:{
            x : "avg(price)",
            y : "sum(price)"
        }
     }
  }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if solrj does not have custom methods like

```
public SolrQuery setFacet(boolean b)
```

etc for the json facets, you can still use them like this:

```
solrQuery.add("json.facet", "..."); 
solrQuery.setParam("json.facet", "...");
```